# Define Route to button action with Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

Hi I have created CRUD interface using Laravel Data tables. And with that I have included a action column as well. As follows

```
    public function getJobs()
    {
        return datatables()->of(Jobs::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function ($jobs) {
                $button = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="edit" id="' . $jobs->id . '" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Edit</button>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="' . $jobs->id . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>';
                $button .= '</div>';
                return $button;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }
```

This code works fine but now I want to add the edit and delete route for these buttons using ajax. I cannot use models since these forms have too much data to edit hence i am using a seperate blade file for editing the data.

My Route:

```
Route::resource('jobs', 'JobsController');
Route::get('/jobs/destroy/', 'JobsController@destroy');
```

My Delete Model Box:

```
<div id="confirmModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 align="center" style="margin:0;">Are you sure you want to remove this job?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" name="ok_button" id="ok_button" class="btn btn-danger">OK</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My ajax code for delete button:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.delete', function(){
            var job_id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#confirmModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#ok_button').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"/jobs/destroy/"+job_id,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#ok_button').text('Deleting...');
                },

            success:function(data)
            {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#confirmModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#jobsTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }, 2000);
            }
        })
    });
```

I would like to know how can I assign a route for these edit and delete buttons.

Comment: Instead of button use <a></a> tag and give url href in attribute

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.

That way I am unable to use a modal box for this delete action. I need a Modal box action for delete function. I have already set up the edit function using a href.

Comment: ok so give click function to button and pass id in parameter of that function. define and implement function into your script

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion pal. My Jquery knowledge is very close to none. :). I barely wrote this code since I have used it previously for some test work. But I will try my best to test your method. Thanks.

Comment: If you want code then i can i update you in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After So much trouble I was able to find the issues with my code:

1. JS rabble- I had so many unnecessary JS scripts loaded into my layout blade and my index blade as well. I loaded the only one JS min into my layout file and then it started to trigger ajax functions.
2. Ajax function Bugs- My Ajax code had somethings missing. Eg: X-CSRF setup etc.

Below is my working code:

**Controller**

```
    public function getJobs()
    {
        return datatables()->of(Jobs::latest()->get())
            ->addColumn('action', function ($jobs) {
                $button = '<div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">';
                $button .= '<a href="/jobs/' . $jobs->id . '/edit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>';
                $button .= '<button type="button" name="deleteButton" id="' . $jobs->id . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteButton"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>&nbsp;Delete</button>';
                $button .= '</div>';
                return $button;
            })
            ->rawColumns(['action'])
            ->make(true);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        Jobs::find($id)->delete();
    }
```

**Index.blade.php**

```
<div id="deleteModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4 align="center" style="margin:0;">Are you sure you want to remove this job?</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" name="ok_button" id="ok_button" class="btn btn-danger">OK</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Ajax Script**

```
var job_id;

    // Delete action
    $(document).on('click', '.deleteButton', function(){
        job_id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#deleteModal').modal('show');
    });

    $('#ok_button').click(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type:'DELETE',
            url:"/jobs/destroy/" + job_id,
        });
            $.ajax({
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#ok_button').text('Deleting...');
                },
            success:function(data)
            {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#jobsTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });


});
```

Thank you everyone for the provided suggestions and pointers. It helped a lot to debug this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add route on click of button ajax like

$button .= '<button type="button" name="delete" id="' . $jobs->id . '" 
class="btn btn-danger btn-xs deleteButton"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"> 
</i>&nbsp;Delete</button>';$button .= '</div>';

$(".deleteButton").on('click', function(event){
var Id = $(this).attr('id');  
/* add route name */
 var ajax_url = '/deleteJobs/'+Id; 
 $.ajax({

        url: ajax_url,
        type: "GET", 
        success: function (data) {
            table.draw();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});

  /* Route */
  Route::get('/deleteJobs/{id}', 'appearQuiz@deleteJobs');

  also, you can get the reference from this URL
   https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-ajax-crud-tutorial-using-datatable-jsexample.html
```

Comment: Hi Shraddha,

Thank you for your valuable time.

I tried your method. But still, it's not even launching the modal box. I have edited my question according to that. Can you help me find what is wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

you have define route for delete button on your ajax is "/jobs/destroy/". so in web.php route became Route::get('/jobs/destroy/{id}', 'appearQuiz@deleteJobs');

and for open model box https://vegibit.com/bootstrap-modal-form-examples/
By click on edit button opens a model and on click of OK button calls ajax where jobs/destroy routes calls.

Comment: Yet It doesn't work. I am unable to figure out the exact root cause of this matter. Modal box doesn't even popup let alone the delete action.